# How does an async mocha test resolve without returning a promise or invoking the done callback

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, mocha.js

I would love to better understand the internals of why the following example works as expected:

```
describe('async await', () => {
    it('resolves without return', async () => {
        await asyncOperation();
    });
});

function asyncOperation() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve();
        }, 123);
    });
}
```

Typically an async mocha test must return a promise (or execute the done callback) but in this example nothing is returned but the mocha test still works. How exactly does this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [`async` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

> The async function declaration defines an asynchronous function, which returns an AsyncFunction object.
>
> **Description**
>
> When an async function is called, **it returns a Promise**. When the async function returns a value, the Promise will be resolved with the returned value.  When the async function throws an exception or some value, the Promise will be rejected with the thrown value.

This means that in your case, a `Promise` is returned, that's why your test works.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `async` keyword, you are implicitly returning a `Promise` of whatever type you actually use in the `return` statement of the function (in this case you aren't returning anything, so this is simply a `Promise` of nothing, or `Promise<void>` if you're into TypeScript).

Internally, a function that uses `async/await` gets unrolled into a number of asynchronous continuations, split at each usage of the `await` keyword. When the promise you are `await`-ing completes, the remainder of the function is resumed. It may be instructive to see how transpilers like Babel unroll your code.

This code:

```
function asyncOperation() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve();
        }, 123);
    });
}

async () => {
    await asyncOperation();
}
```

is transpiled to plain ES5 as:

```
"use strict";

function _asyncToGenerator(fn) { return function () { var gen = fn.apply(this, arguments); return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { function step(key, arg) { try { var info = gen[key](arg); var value = info.value; } catch (error) { reject(error); return; } if (info.done) { resolve(value); } else { return Promise.resolve(value).then(function (value) { step("next", value); }, function (err) { step("throw", err); }); } } return step("next"); }); }; }

function asyncOperation() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            resolve();
        }, 123);
    });
}

_asyncToGenerator(regeneratorRuntime.mark(function _callee() {
    return regeneratorRuntime.wrap(function _callee$(_context) {
        while (1) {
            switch (_context.prev = _context.next) {
                case 0:
                    _context.next = 2;
                    return asyncOperation();

                case 2:
                case "end":
                    return _context.stop();
            }
        }
    }, _callee, undefined);
}));
```

That ugly `_asyncToGenerator` invocation used to be your beautiful async function. It has been unrolled into explicit continuations ([you can try](https://babeljs.io/repl/) adding more await points and logic to the function and seeing how the transpiled code changes).